# Copy constructor doesnt happen when assign a QGraphicsDropShadowEffect object in qt

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

I declared two `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` null pointers due to add shadow effect on some `QPushButton(s)` in `qt` :

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *effectButton1;
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *effectButton2;
```

Then i allocate memory to `effectButton1` and called the `setXOffset`, `setYOffset`, `setBlurRadius` methods to set shadow options to the `effectButton1` object.

```
effectButton1 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effectButton1->setXOffset(3);
effectButton1->setYOffset(3);
effectButton1->setBlurRadius(7);
```

Now, I wanna assign `effectButton1` object to `effectButton2` while creating instance with `new` operator. as you know, in the following statement, copy-constructor must happen and the value that i had set with `setXOffset(3)` must be set to the `effectButton2` memory too. but the return value of `xOffset()` for both objects are different (for `effectButton1` is <kbd>3</kbd> and `effectButton2` is <kbd>8</kbd>) :

```
effectButton2 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(effectButton1);
QMessageBox::information(this, "", QString("%1").arg(effectButton1->xOffset()));
QMessageBox::information(this, "", QString("%1").arg(effectButton2->xOffset()));
```

I expected, when i call `effectButton1->setXOffset(3)` and assign `effectButton1` to `effectButton2` the same value of `XOffset` will be set for `effectButton2` memory because copy-constructor must be happen).

Comment: You're actually creating a new `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` with `effectButton1` as its parent object.  `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` has no copy constructor.

Comment: @G.M. Please explain me exactly. i cant understand.

Comment: Off-topic: "Battle-tested" in Russian is "закалённый в бою". "битва проверено" is not grammatically correct and is just a concatenation of two words without any meaning.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot. i will correct it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the statement...

```
effectButton2 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(effectButton1);
```

That will invoke [this constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html#QGraphicsDropShadowEffect)...

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(QObject *parent)
```

with `effectButton1` as the `parent` parameter.  It doesn't, as you seem to think, call a copy constructor.  Indeed `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` doesn't have a copy constructor as it inherits from `QObject` which is not copyable.

If you want to duplicate the state of `effectButton1` in `effectButton2` you need to copy the appropriate properties manually, e.g...

```
effectButton2 = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
effectButton2->setXOffset(effectButton1->xOffset());
```

etc.

Comment: Isn't that so that сopy-constructor feature will be implement automatically when a class implemented?

Comment: No, there is *no* copy constructor.

Comment: And if we want a copy-constructor, we must implement like this for example : `Class(const Class &c)` isn't it? am i right?